# Creating the same event in multiple calendars

Tags: google-calendar

I manage 72 calendars for my business. How do I create an event that will show up in all these calendars at one time? For instance, I wish to announce Good Friday or Easter Sunday all at one time. Normally, I would place this announcement at the top of the calendar on the respective date.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. The best way is to create a new [shared calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/143754), so the different people who are using the 72 calendars can now view those common events in one place.

Another way to do it is to invite everyone to the event from one calendar. The event will then appear on the calendars of those who you invite.